# Is it possible to automate interaction with an application using bash?

Tags: bash, software-recommendation, automation, testing, hardware-test

We have a graphical application deployed on ubuntu server 16.04. 
Sometimes certain things on this application seize to work properly. 
I'm probably stretching for a long shot but is there anyway I could write test cases to interact with the application using bash?

For instance, sending an email and using the onscreen keyboard to enter the info and send it through our application to the user, or selecting an item and adding it to a users virtual basket. Basically I want to test functions daily without physically being there.

It would also be bonus points if I can deploy this remotely.

I don't know if this would make any difference but but it is a touch device with a ubuntu os that it is deployed on.

Comment: If it's running Xorg, you could use `xdotool` to simulate keyboard and mouse input.

Comment: it does use xorg. I will take a look into it.

Comment: so far it seems pretty much exactly what I need. am I able to set a list of tasks for it to do and get its output and do something along the lines of stick it in a cron job?

Comment: @JermayneWilliams Anything that requires Xorg won't work that well from a cron job, and getting that to work is a lot of hustle IIRC. List of tasks is possible. There's an explanation on that somewhere in the man page.  If the app you're talking about runs within like an actual desktop environment, I'd say it's possible to add an autostart script with some particular `xdotool` commands.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy It's not running on a desktop environment. its running on ubuntu server just auto running the app when it starts up.